# close window.open after trigger click

Tags: jquery, html

how do I close `window.open` after running this code `mailTab.$('input[type="submit"][name="submit"]').trigger('click');`

```
<script src="jscripts/jquery.plugins.min.js?ver=1813"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script>
          $('#certform').ajaxForm(function () {
              var mailTab = window.open("private.php?action=send&uid={$thread['uid']}");


          mailTab.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
              mailTab.$('input[type="text"][name="subject"]').val('Subject');
              mailTab.$('iframe[frameborder="0"]').contents().find('body').html('Hello');
              mailTab.$('input[type="submit"][name="submit"]').trigger('click');

});
location.reload();
                        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add
 `mailTab.close()` after the `mailTab.$('input[type="submit"][name="submit"]').trigger('click');`. Maybe you need to add a TimeOut to.

Comment: adding `mailTab.close()` after `mailTab.$('input[type="submit"][name="submit"]').trigger('click');` will close the window before ` mailTab.$('input[type="submit"][name="submit"]').trigger('click');` run. Is there any way to do it without using TimeOut? I want to have these functions run in the quickest time, without having to wait for extra seconds

Comment: I haven't run your code so I think you can try to run the `mailTab.close()` after the anonymous function.

Comment: if you mean after `DOMContentLoaded` , I have tried that and it will close the window before all the functions